# Problema con los fragmentos en android

Tags: android, android-fragment, fragment

Buenas tardes amigos ire al grano:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


 Fragment currentFragment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu,menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

      switch (item.getItemId()){

          case R.id.mwelcome:
                  this.currentFragment = new  WelcomeFragment();
              break;
                  this.currentFragment = new MapFragment();
          case R.id.map:

              break;

      }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

bueno les cuento me sale error en las dos siguientes lineas:

```
  this.currentFragment = new  WelcomeFragment();
```

y tambien en

```
this.currentFragment = new MapFragment();
```

por si acaso MapFragment y WelcomeFragment los tengo ahi estos son los codigos:

MapFragment:

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment {


public MapFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
}
```

}

WelcomeFragment:

```
public class WelcomeFragment extends Fragment {


public WelcomeFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_welcome, container, false);
    }

 }
```

porfavor ayudenme el error que me sale es:

```
Incompatible types.
Required:
android.support.v4.app.Fragment
Found:
com.example.david.udemy_09_maps.fragments.MapFragment
```

Muchas gracias amigos espero sus ayudas :).

Comment: primero tu clase debe implentar los fragment para poder usarlos

Comment: debes de importar la librería: import android.support.v4.app.Fragment; no la de: import android.app.Fragment;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Fragment currentFragment` es un `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` pero los fragments que estas queriendo asignarle son del tipo `com.example.david.udemy_09_maps.fragments.MapFragment` son clases distintas usa `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` para todos tus fragments y no tendras problema

Comment: muchas gracias por sus ayudas amigos :).